# can't install virtuabbox guest additions or even update kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I've downloaded kali linux from here [osboxes kali linux](http://www.osboxes.org/kali-linux/) because I'm having troubles installing any linux version using virtualbox on my windows laptop. I tried to install virtualbox guest additions this way
[UPDATE:]
I run apt-get update first but nothing to update

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y
```

but the result is

```
Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64
Couldnt find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64'
Couldnt find any package by regex'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64'
```

I tried to update through terminal and fro settings but tells me all updates are installed and there's no new updates

I tried

```
apt -y install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
```

The result is

```
Unable to locate package open-vm-tools-desktop
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

The result

```
0 upgraded 0 newly installed 0 to remove 0 not upgraded
```

I'm new to linux just running kali on virtualbox to study CEH but can't update or install packages. So how to fix this?

[UPDATE]
I added repositories and managed to upgrade kali then in terminal:

```
apt -y install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
```

The result is "fuse and vm tools are installed and alreadyhave the newest version" but still can't find the shared folder from windows (as I can in Parrot)) and still can't drag and drop files

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked which repo you have in the file /etc/apt/sources.list? If you just installed Kali, you might need to replace the cd-rom repos with the standard repos:

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
```

As well as:

```
deb http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/kali/kali-security/ kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: updated please review

Comment: that helped me! thank you! for my case, changed it to this single line `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`
http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade` would be fixed by `apt-get update`.  This needs to be run before the first attempt to install packages, or as the first step in any package update.  Of course, this may just show you a more specific error.

The update through Settings graphical interface likely uses PackageKit.  On your system, it acts as a frontend to `apt-get`.  I'm sorry to say PackageKit can be difficult to understand and troubleshoot.  I think you have the right approach in trying to troubleshoot with specific `apt-get` commands in the terminal, first.

For example, PackageKit has a command-line equivalent to `apt-get update`.  Firstly, you need to know the right options in order to resolve an issue like this:  `pkcon refresh force` or `pkcon -c 1 refresh`.  Secondly, if repos cannot be contacted, it might only list those repos (on Debian), or nothing at all (Fedora IIRC, or if it thinks the computer has no network connection).  The pkcon command does not tend to list more specific errors.  In theory, PackageKit is designed around updating laptops which may or may not have internet access at a given time.  In practice, it fails to handle network interruptions; an attempt to patch this has been submitted some time ago but requires review and has not been responded to at all.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1314991

Comment: I did apt-get update first but nothing updated and I don't have a network issue as I can ping yahoo.com and open websites via iceweasel

Comment: updated please review

Answer (score 0):

added the main repositories to etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade

reboot
```

then followed these steps: https://youtu.be/MkaJ3Nssxac?t=5m49s